# How to perform an action for dynamic data by clicking on checkbox in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap table. In that I want to perform an action when i click on checkbox in table to get Item ID value.

```
<table data-toggle="table" id="table-style" data-row-style="rowStyle" data-url="data/g3.json"  data-show-refresh="true" data-show-toggle="true" data-show-columns="true" data-search="true" data-select-item-name="toolbar1" data-pagination="true" data-sort-name="name" data-sort-order="desc" data-single-select="false" data-click-to-select="true" data-maintain-selected="true">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-field="state" data-checkbox="true"></th>
      <th data-field="id" >Item ID</th>
      <th data-field="name" data-sortable="true">Product Name</th>
      <th data-field="price" data-sortable="true">Actual Price</th>
      <th data-field="discount_price" data-sortable="true">Discount Price</th>
      <th data-field="stock_avail" data-sortable="true">Stock Available</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Jquery function :

```
$("input[name='btSelectItem']").on("click","input[name='btSelectItem']",function(){
        alert("Hello");
        var values = "";
         $.each($("input[name='btSelectItem']:checked"), function(index, value) {
             var data = $(this).parents('tr:eq(0)');
             if(index > 0)
                 values ++;
             values +=$(data).find('td:eq(1)').text();
         });
         alert(values);
   });
```

When i click on checkbox my function was not calling, Kindly help me to resolve this. Thanks in advance

Below is my table Code :

```
<table id="eventsTable" class="table table-striped table-hover" data-id-field="id" data-toolbar="#toolbar" data-show-columns="true" data-show-toggle="true" data-show-refresh="true" data-search="true" data-url="data/g3.json" data-height="300" data-toggle="table" style="margin-top: -41px;">
<thead>
<tbody>
<tr class="selected" data-index="0">
<td class="bs-checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" name="btSelectItem" data-index="0">
</td>
<td style="">Test</td>
<td style="">21</td>
<td style="">High</td>
<td style="">Low</td>
<td style="">High</td>
<td style="">100</td>
</tr>
<tr data-index="1">
<td class="bs-checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" name="btSelectItem" data-index="1">
</td>
<td style="">Test2</td>
<td style="">26</td>
<td style="">High</td>
<td style="">Low</td>
<td style="">Medium</td>
<td style="">50</td>
</tr>
<tr data-index="2">
<tr data-index="3">
<tr data-index="4">
<tr data-index="5">
<tr data-index="6">
<tr data-index="7">
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides the selector was wrong, the problem is that bootstrap table js code captures the event when you click and stops its propagation, so it never bubbles up and you can't capture on a document level.

The good news is that it provides an API to capture such events. In this case you can use several events like `onCheck`, `onCheckSome`, as noted in the [docs](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/documentation/#events), e.g.:

```
$('#table-style').on("check.bs.table", myFunc);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already attaching the event handler to the input element, you don't need any further filter in `on`.
Try with:

```
$(document).on("click", "input[name='btSelectItem']", function(){ ... })
```

Comment: Hi Dario, thanks for the reply. I tried with your approach still my function is not getting called.

Comment: I can't see any matched element in the code you posted, you need to write more. You can also check this simple pen http://codepen.io/dariospadoni/pen/LRkpko